# Is there an opposite for the saying "winner winner chicken dinner"?

Tags: phrase-requests

Maybe something like, "loser loser drunken boozer"?

I couldn't find examples online, other things come up in a search.

A scenario to be used in would be when someone loses a competition and they are mocking the loser.

Answers should be something that has been used before, in contrast to the original phrase.

Comment: [Urban Dictionary lists that one](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=loser%20loser%20drunken%20boozer) but it doesn't seem to be used elsewhere.

Comment: Ok I didn't find that and thought I just made it up

Comment: Google tells me that "loser loser double loser" was once a children's rhyme (in some areas?) but I can't find a good source for that.

Comment: @user14094230 Have you seen the [help on the phrase-requests tag](/tags/phrase-requests/info)? Please [edit] your question in line with the checklist.

Comment: There is no common/established version for "loser loser <rhyming phrase>. It can be considered a snowclone and you can finish with whatever rhyming phrase you want. A clever version I've seen in an article: "Loser loser now who's dinner?"

Comment: Ok, that would be an answer.

Comment: I considered it as a helpful comment. "Loser loser double loser" appears to be the most common version as alphabet mentioned before, perhaps more common in speech. They could consider posting an answer.

Comment: @alphabet I remember that from when I was a child

Comment: "winner winner chicken dinner"? Is that something you hear after a basketball game somewhere in the US?  Sounds like it might be out of the movie *Hoosiers*.

Comment: If someone wins $20 in a scratch off lottery ticket, it may be a likely response.

Comment: It was "I'm the king of the castle, you're a dirty rascal" when I was small.

Comment: @StuartF It was always a 'the dirty wee rascal' round our way, scans better.

Answer (score 0):

“Snoozer Snoozer now your a loser” aka “you snooze you lose” or maybe something like “Loser Loser your a snoozer” makes sense too

Comment: It may make sense, but I don't think it's an accepted phrase.

Answer (score -2):

"you snooze, you lose"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).